# videojs player does not play when poster image is available

Tags: wordpress, video.js

A client is using videojs in their wordpress theme and I am trying to figure out why when I add a poster to the video, the video does not ever 'buffer' or play.  It sits there with the 'loading' spinner, but it will never play.

When I remove the poster (thumbnail) from the player, the video plays just fine.

I am using this shortcode in wordpress:

```
[videojs mp4="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4", poster="http://moviewriternyu.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/mclovin-license.jpg"]
```

If I remove the `, poster="http://...` the video plays just fine.

Has this happened for anyone else?

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

Videojs player does not like commas.  `,` between any of it's inputs.  Here's the right way to write it:

```
[videojs mp4="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" poster="http://moviewriternyu.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/mclovin-license.jpg"]
```

Just removed the `,` before `poster`

Answer (score 0):

[videojs mp4="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4", poster="http://moviewriternyu.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/mclovin-license.jpg"]

You have placed a comma between attributes but it is not allowed. Remove it and play the video.